# Probability (arranging around a circle)

Tags: probability

What is the probability that when arranging n people around a circle, two people with the same birthday (assume no leap years) will be adjacent to each other?

Comment: multiply the probability two people out of $n$ have birthday on the same day by the probability that they occupy adjacent seats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probability model is not quite clear. If you have $n$ given people and arrange them randomly, the probability you ask for is $1$ if the $n$ people all have the same birthday, $0$ if they all have different birthdays. I don't think that's what you meant to ask. Reading between the lines, I'm guessing that the $n$ people at your round table are an independent random sample from an infinite population where all $365$ birthdays are equally likely. In that case, the number of possible outcomes is $365^n$, while the number of outcomes where no two people in adjacent seats have the same birthday is $364^n+364(-1)^n$. Hence the probability that **no** two people with the same birthday are sitting next to each other is $\dfrac{364^n+364(-1)^n}{365^n}$, and your answer is $1-\dfrac{364^n+364(-1)^n}{365^n}$.

The numerator is obtained by setting $t=365$ in the expression $(t-1)^n+(t-1)(-1)^n$, the [chromatic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Examples) of the cycle graph $C_n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy or obvious question, as you need to figure out how many pairs among the n people have the same birthday. One approach is to consider the opposite: compute the probability that people who are adjacent to each other have different birthdays.

Let $a_n$ be the numbers of ways that n people around a circle, such that any two adjacent persons have different birthdays. We begin with the $1^{st}$ person whose birthday is fixed, so the $2^{nd}$ have $365-1=364$ choices, and the rest can be done in the same manner. However, we need pay attention to the $(n-2)^{th}$ person.

1. If the $(n-2)^{th}$ person has the same birthday with the $1^{st}$ one, then the $(n-1)^{th}$ person has $365-1=364$ choices.
2. If the $(n-2)^{th}$ person's birthday is different from the $1^{st}$ person's, then the $(n-1)^{th}$ person has $365-2=363$ choices.

Hence we have the following recurrence relation:
$$
a_n=364\,a_{n-2}+363\,a_{n-1}
$$
Thanks to user 14111, I need be carful enough to get $a_1=0$, $a_2=365*364$ and $a_3=365*364*363$, solve the above equation we get $$a_n=364*(364^{n-1}+(-1)^n)$$
The desired probability is $1-\frac{a_n}{365^{n}}$, assuming there are 365 days in a year.

PS: This is a typical Olympic Math queston for high school students, and I did an almost the same one 7 years ago in one competition. I'm afraid I didn't work it out at that time, but the way to solve sank deep into my memory.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe I need to begin with $a_2$ and $a_3$, but I think the method is correct, and it is 11 p.m. in my place. I will edit it the next day, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @user14111 Well, I should be more careful with $a_1$. I wonder how you obtain the formula for chromatic polynomial, is there a better way to solve this problem?